# Have I obtained the correct simplified transfer function for this RLC circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, transfer-function

Have I obtained the correct simplified transfer function for this RLC circuit?

I am trying to obtain the transfer function for the following RCL circuit. However, the response of the TF that I obtain doesn't correlate to the response of the circuit itself when I simulate it. Please see below:

[image]

Therefore, I have obviously done something wrong. I have spent a good couples of days and plenty of scrap papers trying to see where I have missed something, but I keep on arriving at the same answer.

So, in order to save myself the headache of repeatedly doing the same thing only to obtain the same outcome, I've decided to put my dilemma to the community!

Below is my working out from the mid-way point to the end result and if anyone can spot or point out what I have missed, I would really appreciate it.

So the starting expression is:

$$ I_2(s)((\frac{C_2Ls^3+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1}{C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s})(\frac{C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1}{C_1s}))-I_2(s)(Ls+R_1)=E_i(s)\tag{1} $$

$$ I_2(s)((\frac{C_2Ls^3+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1}{C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s})(\frac{C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1}{C_1s})-(Ls+R_1))=E_i(s) $$

$$ I_2(s)(\frac{(C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1)({C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1})}{(C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s)(C_1s)})-(Ls+R_1))=E_i(s) $$

$$ I_2(s)(\frac{(C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1)(C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1)-(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls+R_1)}{(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)})\tag{2}$$

Expanding the numerator for the positive term

$$ (C_2Ls^2+C_2(R1+R2)s+1)(C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1)$$

$$ (C_2Ls^2)(C_1Ls^2) + (C_2Ls^2)(C_1R_1s) + (C_2Ls^2)(1) + (C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(C_1Ls^2) + (C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(C_1R_1s)+(C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(1)) + (1)(C_1Ls^2) + (1)(C_1R_1s) + (1)(1) $$

$$ (C_1C_2L^2s^4) + (C_1C_2R_1Ls^3) + (C_2Ls^2) + (C_1C_2L(R_1+R_2)s^3) + (C_1C_2R_1(R_1+R_2)s^2) + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + (C_1Ls^2) + (C_1R_1s) + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2L(R_1+R_2)s^3 + C_1C_2R_1(R_1+R_2)s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 \tag{3}$$

Expanding the numerator for the negative term

$$ -(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls+R_1)$$

$$ -((C_1C_2Ls^3)(Ls)+(C_1C_2Ls^3)(R_1)+(C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls)+(C_1C_2R_1s^2)(R_1))$$

$$ -(C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2)\tag{4}$$

Subtracting \$(4)\$ from \$(3)\$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 -C_1C_2L^2s^4 - C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 - C_1C_2L^2s^4 - 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 $$

$$ C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

Combining like terms

$$ C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1 $$

Therefore, I get

$$ I_2(s)\frac{C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1}{C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2} = E_i(s)$$

And I arrive at this final transfer function each and every time:

$$ \frac{I_2(s)}{E_i(s)}=\frac{C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2}{C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1} \tag{5}$$

Therefore, if anyone has noted any step(s) that I might have missed, I would really appreciate it, if you could please point it out :)

Comment: Algebra soup, again? Did you first work out the unitless transfer function for Ex/Ei, first? Because you can use the same technique again with that, if you do (as I mentioned before.) Also, did you get sympy, yet? I definitely encourage you to be able to work this with your fingers and some sand. No question. But at some point, it's helpful to get a tool that "just works right" and you can then often use it to show you your own errors.

Comment: I C a lot of el-seas and would expect the answer to have an equivalent parallel C and or series C result instead of just product terms. Have you tried KVL or Thevenin or other approaches to impedance? Pretend each component is just Z(s) for Z1 to Z5

Comment: By the way, I think your bottom formula may be right.

Comment: @jonk hahaha. Unfortunately :) Tbh, I'm still not too clear on how to obtain $E_o(s)/E_i(s)$ from $I_2(s)/E_i(s)$ and if what I'm getting is actually $I_2(s)/E_i(s)$ or $E_o(s)/E_i(s)$, given as somestimes the TF works without the added impedancce at the output and other times the added impedance gives a different response to what is expected. So, i'm still trying to figure a lot of things out atm :) But, I do need to get onto the sympy thing, if it'll make my life easier!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I actually used KVL to arrive at the starting expression. I tend to try to stay well clear of Thevenin and Norton methods. I'm not quite sure what it is about those methods that gives me a headache :) I initially started off with the Complex Impedance method, but it was throwing up even more trickier algebra!

Comment: @jonk by bottom formula, do you mean (5)?

Comment: @aLoHa Yeah, I do. Assuming I2(s) means what I think it does.

Comment: @jonk So, is the issue the way that I have entered it into LTspice then?

Comment: @aLoHa Maybe. I didn't look to see what in the heck you are doing there.

Comment: @aLoHa I'm not sure how you are using the E type there, but if I had to guess I'd say its supposed to be given a unitless transfer function so it can map an input V to an output V.  But you are supplying I/Vin which is not unitless. If my random guess about it makes any sense then you are misusing E here. But then I'm not at all sure how that works. Normally, it's a unitless transform for E's input to output. What you are doing kind of doesn't make sense right now. But I'm not sufficiently familiar with the approach in LTspice when you are using a laplace function that carries units, either.

Comment: @aLoHa Looking at the help, Mike also talks about "[window=<time>] [nfft=<number>] [mtol=<number>]" as possibly being important. I honestly haven't used LTspice for this kind of purpose before. So I'm up in the air about it's appropriate usage in LTspice. Finally, you've clicked on V(x) for a comparison plot, which is, I think, Vx/Vin and not Ic2/Vin.

Comment: @aLoHa As per the other answers until now, all you have to do is to express \$I_2\$ as a function of the voltage across \$C_2\$: \$I_2=V_2sC_2\$. This means the final expression will be \$\dfrac{V_2sC_2}{E_i}\$, with an extra \$sC_2\$ in the numerator, which makes the whole right hand expression be divided by it, leaving you with the desired transfer function. If you visually compare the two responses then you'll notice that the difference between them is a slope; in this case, the one given by \$sC_2\$.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I just now tried entering the I/V function that I checked against aloha's eq. (5). Matches exactly with the current in C2. And when I took what I get for Vx/Vin and put that in, it matches exactly again. I've learned something new about LTspice, which I most definitely will use in the future. I had read the help before but never explored it before now. Useful. Anyway, all I'm getting is exactly what I'd expect to get. No questions at all. It just works nice.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I just rapidly posted it up. I think things are fine.

Comment: @jonk I would have found it to be very worrying if it were otherwise. :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for your input, which is always welcomed.

Comment: @aLoHa Your goal is to find the voltage gain, so you need \$E_o(s)/E_i(s)\$. Since you obtained the \$I_2(s)/E_i(s)\$, you need to convert \$I_2(s)\$ to \$E_o(s)\$, somehow. Since, \$E_o(s)=V_2(s)\$ and since \$V_2(s)\$ is the voltage across \$C_2\$, then it follows that extracting \$V_2(s)\$ from \$I_2(s)\$ is the next logical step. Thus, all you need is the expression for \$I_2(s)\$, which is $$I_2(s)=sV_2(s)C_2\Rightarrow V_2(s)=\dfrac{I_2(s)}{sC_2}=\mathrm{<your\,expression>}$$ The \$sC_2\$ terms cancel, leaving you with the desired tranfer function. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schematic is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZrouo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above, you can see that \$R_2\$ and \$Z_2\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_Y\$ into \$V_\text{OUT}\$. It follows that:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Each Stage}
&\left\{
  \begin{array}{rl}
V_\text{OUT} &= V_Y\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}&\text{where}&Z_2 &= \left(Z_{C_2}\mid\mid \infty\right)=Z_{C_2}\\\\
V_Y &= V_\text{IN}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{Z_{C_1}}{Z_1}}&\text{where}&Z_1 &= \left(Z_{L_1}+R_1\right)\mid\mid \left(Z_2 + R_2\right)
  \end{array}
\right.\\\\
&\therefore \frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{Z_{C_1}}{Z_1}}\right]\cdot\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}\right]\\\\
&\therefore \frac{I_{C_2}}{V_\text{IN}}=\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{Z_{C_1}}{Z_1}}\right]\cdot\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}\right]\cdot\bigg[C_2\,s\bigg]
\end{align*}$$

Let's do this in **sympy**:

```
var('l1 c2 r1 r2 c1 vy vout vin')
zc1=1/s/c1                               # C1 impedance
zc2=1/s/c2                               # C2 impedance
zl1=s*l1                                 # L1 impedance
z2=zc2                                   # Z2 is just C2's impedance
z1=(zl1 + r1)*(z2+r2)/(zl1+r1+z2+r2)     # Z1 = parallel combination, as shown
f1=1/(1+zc1/z1)                          # first fraction
f2=1/(1+r2/z2)                           # second fraction
simplify(f1*f2*c2*s)                     # transfer function of I(C2)/V(IN)
    c1*c2*s**2*(l1*s + r1)/(c1*s*(l1*s + r1)*(c2*r2*s + 1) + c2*s*(l1*s + r1 + r2) + 1)
simplify(f1*f2)                          # transfer function of V(x)/V(IN)
    c1*s*(l1*s + r1)/(c1*s*(l1*s + r1)*(c2*r2*s + 1) + c2*s*(l1*s + r1 + r2) + 1)
```

Then I just built this schematic:

[image]

And got this result:

[image]

So what's the problem?? I think you need to look more closely either at your algebra process or else for typos in your laplace function. I used a direct "copy/paste" operation directly from sympy to LTspice, to minimize the chances for error.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sometimes, it's quite dififcult to see the woods from the trees when you have several papers of algebra littered all of the place :) and I haven't quite yet mastered the syntax for LTspice.

Comment: I believe that I may already have Sympy, as I have Python packages already installed on my PC. So, I'll get back to you via the chatroom on how to go about installing the Sympy package!

Comment: @aLoHa Yeah. You know how to do the algebra, already. It's just that you can make mistakes. You're human. So don't keep forcing yourself to waste precious life blood on something you already know well -- algebra and at least the part of laplace that applies here. Focus on the bigger things, now. Let sympy take care of the algebra for you. It's an acceptable aide now that you know the other stuff well enough. Also, I tend to use 2000 pts per decade. That advice came from Mike, himself. So it's probably good advice.

Comment: Hi @jonk, I was hoping to get back too you via the chatroom, regarding how to install the Sympy package. But it is apparently frozen and I do not know how to start a new chat.

Comment: @aLoHa Try [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123444/aloha-and-jonk). I'm just learning how to do this, myself. So who knows?

Answer (score 4):

When I see the amount of lines thrown on the blank page by the OP as an attempt to derive this 3rd-order transfer function, I think it is about time time that fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs are taught in universities. The principle is simple and, very often, works with *inspection*: just look at the circuit to infer the time constants without writing a single line of algebra. The exercise consists of determining the resistance \$R\$ offered by each energy-storing element when the circuit is observed with a zeroed excitation or with a nulled response. Once you have the \$R\$, you can form a time constant expressed as \$\tau=RC\$ or \$\tau=\frac{L}{R}\$.

So we start with a bunch of small sketches to determine the *natural* time constants of this linear circuit. We reduce the excitation to zero volt (the input source is replaced by a short circuit) and you "look" through the energy-storing element temporarily disconnected from the circuit to find the resistance \$R\$ driving that element:

[image]

As you can see, you just inspect the drawing to see, in your head, what resistance the terminals in question offer (where the arrow points). And if you make a mistake, it is easy and fast to come back to the circuit and correct the resistance \$R\$ you mistakenly determined.

For the zeroes, you can do what is a called a null double injection (NDI) but I often prefer for the passive case, to determine high-frequency gains: the source is back in place and you inspect the circuit to determine what the gains are when energy-storing elements are alternately placed in their high-frequency state:

[image]

You can see how easy it is! When you have all these elements on hand, you assemble them in a Mathcad sheet which a) will check homogeneity of the formulas and b) will let you compare the response obtained by the FACTs and that delivered by the brute-force approach (Thévenin in this case):

[image]

Then you can plot the magnitude and phase while comparing the two responses in similar plots. They perfectly match as shown below:

[image]

You can see how easy the FACTs are compared to the classical KVL and KCL methods. You apply the *divide-and-conquer* strategy promoted by Dr. Middlebrook and solve your circuit step-by-step with the ability to come back and solve an intermediate wrong result. There is no way you can do that with the brute-force approach.

Acquiring the FACTs skill is simple and you can start with 1st-order circuits as shown in the [APEC seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) I taught in 2016. Then, for an in-depth description of the method up to the order \$N\$, you can have a look at the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I published on the subject.

Comment: I'm not comfortable teaching these. So I'm very glad to see the moments offered when you show up like this. Thanks.

Comment: @jonk, I am glad if my contribution helps. I am sure that if you try the FACTs you won't come back to the classical approach ^_^ Cheers!

Comment: I've tried them. Just not yet enough. But enough to know I want to try them more. I just have so much ease and certainty with other methods and sufficient imagination that I can "find" the time constants directly in the equations from inspection (or else easily from standard approaches I otherwise use.) Those things I've done and tested over and over. I just need to find the enjoyable time for FACTs and then to compare my mindset for both, later. (I did get your 2016 book and I've read some. Just haven't had time to do it justice yet.)